# What is the exact algorithm and functions of the 4 way handshake?

Tags: wpa2-psk

I have to make a detailed diagram of the 4 way handshake and formulas for its functions so I need to know the exact process behind it. Like precisely what functions are used in it?

I have been trying to search this for days but all I can find is very "on the surface" level of information. For example it says that the PTK is produced by concatenating PMK, AP nonce, STA nonce, AP MAC address, and STA MAC address and then is put through the PBKDF2-SHA1 hash function. That is all good but the problem for me is that there are no details in that description. Given only information like that I can't make detailed step by step diagram about the 4 way handshake.

To put it in one question what is the precise description of the functions in the 4 way handshake? Also in which algorithm are they sequenced?